# class not found error in android studio

Tags: java, android, exception

Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.mycompany.trial1.Activity1");

I've been trying to write the code for a small android project.
When I declared a class item using Class.forname("  ") using fully specified name, it is still showing as class not found in android studio.
I've seen this implementation in NEWBOSTON video and tried to implement it.

Can anyone tell me how to rectify this ?
Thank You.

Comment: Please post the exact Error from LogCat

Comment: @MDMalik He's not getting the error in Logcat, he's getting it trying to write the code in Android Studio.

Comment: Why are you trying to use forname() ? If you're just starting out, that doesn't seem to be something you'd want to do.

Comment: I have multiple classes in my Android project each of it does a seperate Activity. I wanted to shift from one activity to another activity, So I'm trying to create a Class variable "ourclass" which can reference another class which runs another activity. "ourclass" used to reference the class "Activity1" in "com.mycompany.trial1.Activity1" where "com.mycompany.trial1" is my package name

Answer (score 0):

It sound like your trying to declare a class using Class.forName(), which is a terrible idea. That's not how Java works.

To create a class, you could write this:

```
class MyClass {
    int foo;
    String bar;

    public MyClass(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you *get* Java

Comment: I'm not trying to declare a class, but rather assigning a variable which can reference to an already declared class "Activity1" in the fully classified name "com.mycompany.trial1.Activity1".